# Include specific javascript configuration in Magento website

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript

I'm just getting started with the Magento CMS and I am not sure that it can do what I need right know. 
I need to include some custom javascript in every pages of my site :

- One line of js code in `<head>`
- At the end of the `body` a remote script like : `<script src="https://..." type="text/javascript"></script>` followed by some inline js.

I have seen other answer on this topic but nothing would really fit this particular requirement. Is it even possible to do something like this with magento ? (I am using Magento 2.1.5)

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself. I was looking for something complex but this is in fact pretty easy.

1. Access the admin dashboard and authentificate
2. In content -> Design -> Configuration, Select the store you want to add your script into and select Edit
3. For the `head` part, just past the code into HTML Head ->  Scripts and Style Sheets
4. For the `body` part just past the code into Footer -> Miscalleneous HTML
5. Click Save Configuration
6. In System -> Tools -> Cache Management. Select all items and Submit a Refresh
7. Finally browse to your website and open the developer console to be sure that your js is loaded.